# How do I increase the 2mB uploadifive limit in Geoserver installed on AWS?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, php, amazon-web-services

I've recently migrated a site from Geoserver 2.1.4 installed on a hardware server to Geoserver 2.7.0 installed on an Amazon Web Service. The site uses uploadifive to enable the user to upload a pdf to a different server. This functions exactly the same except there is a 2Mb file size limit for uploads on the AWS which we didn't have on the old server. I've updated the javascript code to overwrite this but it doesn't appear to solve the issue:

```
j('#file_upload').uploadifive({
      'buttonText'       : 'Add Attachment',
      'height'           : 20,
      'queueSizeLimit'   : 1,  
      'fileSizeLimit'    : 20480, // 20Mb should be enough
      'auto'             : true,
      'removeCompleted'  : true,
      'queueID'          : 'asset_queue',
      'uploadScript'     : self.options.strAssetHost + 'uploadifive/uploadifive.php',
      'onSelect'         : function(file) { j("#asset_name").text(''); },
      'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { 
        j("#asset_name").text(file.name); 
        self.strFilename = data;
      }
});
```

Most of the research I've done has pointed me towards adjusting the php.ini file, however I can't seem to find it anywhere and when I create a phpinfo file and navigate to it php doesn't appear to be running. The only things that have changed are the version of Geoserver and server itself so I'm fairly certain there should a setting or a configuration file somewhere to adjust the upload limit, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22488908/uploadifive-file-size-limit-issue help?